# Как ставить объект в качестве аргумента

Tags: pascal

```
function vertex_finder(func: object): integer;
```

правильно ли я задаю объект в качестве аргумента?

Comment: «Правильно» в смысле синтаксиса языка (какого именно диалекта?) или «правильно» с точки зрения логики (какой именно?).

Comment: у меня выдается потом ошибка, что func.b не существует, хотя такое свойство есть

Answer (score 0):

Нет, неправильно.

```
function vertex_finder(func: TFuncType): integer;
```